# How to restrict a user to stored procedures only?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

MySQL version 5.1.70-cll

phpMyAdmin version 3.5.8

cpanel version 11

How do I restrict a user to executing stored procedures only?

In cpanel I can add/remove users, and restrict them to only the 'select' command or only the 'create' command. However, 'call' is not present in the user privileges list.

I also cannot log in as 'root' as far as I can tell. (I am a MySQL newbie sorry.)

Thanks.

Comment: This question is not programming related. Secondly, did you read the manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just grant the user `EXECUTE` permissions on any stored procedures you would like them to be able to execute, and don't give them any other permissions on the tables.

Keep in mind that if the user has no permissions on the tables, you'll need to use `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` when you create your procedures.

Comment: How do I from within cpanel or phpmyadmin restrict a user to a particular table? So far I've only been able to restrict them to a particular database.

Comment: @posfan12 - Just use the SQL editor in phpMyAdmin to manually run the appropriate GRANT statements.

Answer (score 0):

The `EXECUTE` privilege is required to call stored procedures.

Documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines-privileges.html